# php to get 2 string inside href tag with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I need a code to get this strings from inside a href tag

Example of weburl:

```
/video/funny-videos-with-dogs-21608674/
```

**The strings what i need is:**

Url Title = funny-videos-with-dogs

Url ID = 21608674

How i can get this 2 strings from the url via preg_match?

**Update:**

What i try so far is:

```
preg_match('/\/video\/(.*?)-/is', $vUrl, $vUrl_Title);
```

but is show me just "funny" ... i need something to can show "funny-videos-with-dogs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be an easy one:

```
<?php

if (preg_match("#/video/([a-z\-]+)-([0-9]+)/#", "/video/funny-videos-with-dogs-21608674/", $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
  $urlTitle = $matches[1];
  $urlID    = $matches[2];
}
else {
  print_r("Not found!");
}
```

And this yells

```
Array
(
    [0] => /video/funny-videos-with-dogs-21608674/
    [1] => funny-videos-with-dogs
    [2] => 21608674
)
```

Taking into account that non other chars should be matched. I'm pretty sure you can simplify the regexp, I don't have a deep regexp knowledge but this should work